# How does SO manage tags?

Tags: discussion, tags, organization, taxonomy

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How is the tagging system implemented here at S[O|F|U]?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/25710/how-is-the-tagging-system-implemented-here-at-sofu)

I am currently building a website in which users can tag a submission, similar to that of SO, Flickr etc.

I'm just wondering how SO manages all the tags on here - what does the taxonomy look like?

More generally - I am struggling to decide to normalize the data or not. What is the best practice here?

Thank you,

**Edit:** I have seen [this entry on tagging](http://www.pui.ch/phred/archives/2005/06/tagsystems-performance-tests.html), but still am unsure which approach is best overall.

Answer (score 7):

Take a look at how tags are stored in the [data dump](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/category/cc-wiki-dump/).

Answer (score 5):

I will assume you are not expecting an answer from Jeff Atwood, so let's speculate:

You will need three tables:

i) a TAG table

ii) a Questions table

iii) a table to implement the TAG-QUESTION relationship that will have (at least) the keys of both tables.

I would never, no matter what performance considerations, think about a non normalized solution for this!.

Comment: Well, since SO has a hard limit of five tags per question they can probably get rid of the question/tag relation table and store the tags directly in the question table. But in general I agree: Worry about performance if it becomes a problem, not at a point where you having nothing to test and profile yet.

Comment: Yes, I don't want to imagine that code checking for the tags on the fields tag1, tag2, tag3...

Comment: No - I wasn't expecting an answer from Jeff necessarily. But one would be nice :).
Speculating sounds good to me - I appreciate any insight on the topic.

Comment: +1 - You should definitely worry about normalizing first, and performance second. If performance becomes a problem, having normalized tags is probably not going to hurt when you're trying to optimize...

Comment: Over that, I suppose the SO database to be very manageable, only 180.000 questions (until today) and not so many simultaneous viewers.