# How is the tagging system implemented here at S[O|F|U]?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow

We have a home-grown learning management system (LMS - highly abused term, but I'll be damned if I can find a more succinct way of putting it) that includes a list of classroom classes (filed under various categories) and a list of online educational modules (filed under various categories) - and there have been some (justified) complaints about it being difficult to find things.

I've read a couple of articles on creating a tagging system, and have seen a number of implementations. I was curious as to how the S[O|F|U] implementation was set up as it seems to be much better than most of what I've found.

Please don't hear what I'm not saying: I don't want the code handed to me on a silver platter. I'm just curious as to the general DB/Infrastructure used for the tags here as I like the system much better than what I've found elsewhere.

Comment: SOFU is just one space away from being vulgar.

Comment: S OFU​​​​​​​​​?

Comment: Oh yeah, I also find http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tofu offensive :)

Comment: I find Wikipedia offensive. And you. And also `(We|Ouè)lbo[u_]?g(ue)?|Susan( Papadismgaogenabhieanae(laegkae)?)?` whose identity can only be accurately described with a regex.

Comment: Welbog's name is not regular. He will take offence on that.

Answer (score 6):

The db model is the easy part, the tricky part is the find-as-you-type implementations which auto-completes tags, it is tricky to get it working properly cause of various browser annoyances (finding where the cursor is, is non-trivial).

On the DB side a PostsTags and Tags table should be enough to get you going.

From a performance perspective, you have to cache total counts per tag and don't want to end up in deadlock central.

Then you may also want to look at [Tag synonyms](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/70710/152859) so for example if someone tags a topic with c# you could automatically retag to c-sharp.

Finally you may want to consider admin tags. (tags that can only be applied by admins)

Comment: Total counts aren't going to be an issue, and I'm not sure I want to venture in the quagmire that the synonyms is likely to end up... but I like the admin tags. This does sound similar to the infrastructure behind the categories, so I may leave it the way it is and just change the display end of it.