# [mt4] or [metatrader4] or [metatrader] for MetaTrader-related questions on SO

Tags: support, stack-overflow, tags

Currently [metatrader4](/questions/tagged/metatrader4) has 3 questions, and [mt4](/questions/tagged/mt4) - 4 questions.

But I don't think that an abbreviation is more suitable while full name is more recognizable and fits well in tag length limit.

Also common [metatrader](/questions/tagged/metatrader) isn't used at all. Similarly to new, 5 version of MT - [metatrader5](/questions/tagged/metatrader5), [mt5](/questions/tagged/mt5)

What do you think? In my opinion, common [metatrader](/questions/tagged/metatrader) is the best.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some of those, like [metatrader4](/questions/tagged/metatrader4) and [mt4](/questions/tagged/mt4), seem perfectly equivalent, so a [tag synonym relationship](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/70710/what-are-tag-synonyms-how-do-they-work) should be created. I don't know anything about MetaTrader though, so I don't know if it's the kind of product where merging different versions into one synonym relationship is appropriate.