# Tag synonym collision: a valid tag is used as a synonym for an unrelated tag

Tags: discussion, feature-request, tag-synonyms

Amazon-s3 is using the synonym s3. Now, S3 is also an [object oriented implementation in R](http://www.r-bloggers.com/the-s3-oop-system/), but there is no way we can use that tag any more. Every time we apply it, it gets automatically converted to amazon-s3. How do we avoid that conversion?

I can see that this kind of collisions will only occur more often. Isn't it time to get a more strict policy on that tag-synonym thing? See also the [FAQ entry](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/70710/what-are-tag-synonyms-how-do-they-work) on this

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why not make the R related tags language specific e.g. `r-s3`. We do pretty much the same for many other languages and it avoids tag clashes quite nicely.

Comment: Seems a nice workaround, thx for pointing that out, but still you keep the possibility of tag clashes. So I would hope they implement some possibility to have a synonym reversed without adding a question on meta. For all I know, users will now use s3 instead of r-s3 and will see amazon-s3 as their tag. So the tag s3 shouldn't be used as a synonym for any of the language-specific tags.

Comment: @joris - Hopefully once a few questions are tagged `r-s3`, when people are type the `r` it'll show up in the auto-complete which should give a hint that `r-s3` is the tag they want for `s3` stuff.

Comment: If we create an r-s3 tag, it would be sensible to rename the s4 tag.

Comment: @csgillespie - that would make a lot of sense.