# Why we don't make the Tag synonyms suggestion work as for the suggested edits?

Tags: feature-request, tag-synonyms, suggested-edits, retag-request

I spotted those 2 tags.

**[validator](/questions/tagged/validator)  X 150**
**[validators](/questions/tagged/validators) X 242**

I checked If I could propose a [Tag synonyms and how they work](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/70710/what-are-tag-synonyms-how-do-they-work) but I don't have the 2500 reputation needed to suggest a tag synonyms.

Meanwhile I spotted a bunch of [Tag merge request](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=Tag%20merge%20request) here on meta, So [I posted it as such](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/88332/tag-merge-request-validator-and-validators), but I think it's [please an insert the appropriate word here].

Since there is a mechanism that allow Tag synonyms suggestion, why we could not extend it so low rep users could Suggest Tag synonyms need to be approved by Mods before going to vote for further approbation by the community?

Comment: Sorry, I tried to suggest it as my first synonym (I got to the 2.5K mark today) but it requires 5 points in the tag even for 2500 rep users...

Comment: @Aleadam another reason to implement this kind of mechanism.

Comment: To extend [on Jeff's](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/88333/why-we-dont-make-the-tag-synonyms-suggestion-work-as-for-the-suggested-edits/88593#88593) *Synonyms are far more dangerous* a bit: when selecting a synonym, the question is actually tagged with its "master". So: undoing a synonym-master relationship does not fix the questions that have meanwhile been tagged erroneously.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You really, really don't want low rep users suggesting tag synonyms in my experience.

(Also, you're cheating a bit by showing the absolute simplest possible synonym: one word is a plural of another.)

There's a reason the tag *creation* rep level keeps creeping up over time on Stack Overflow; it's the only rep privilege level to do so.

Synonyms are far more dangerous than merely creating a new tag, too.

Comment: But, Is posting a Tag merge request on meta an appropriate behavior?

Comment: And, as my question (http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/120706/tag-synonyms-on-main-stackoverflow-site) and mgrus's question (http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/89576/flag-synonym-suggestion-for-moderator) both imply, it seems that people just don't care about this enough for it to happen. I'd suggest either that the tag synonym threshold needs to be _a lot_ lower or that there should be a method of suggesting them for moderator approval, as DavRob60 proposes here.

Comment: @owen the mods periodically will view the pending synonyms list and push through the ones that make sense. http://stackoverflow.com/tags/synonyms

Comment: @JeffAtwood: Yes, I gather that's the case, it's just that almost no-one is able to suggest new synonyms; the threshold is quite high, as well as requiring a rept of 5 on the tags themselves. It just feels like a "suggested synonyms" list (like the suggested edits to questions and answers) might be helpful.

Answer (score 4):

It does make sense. If anyone can even suggest a tag wiki edit, even more the user should be able to suggest tag synonyms.

The only reason I see to not do it is if the low volume of request makes the issue non-relevant. If there are just a few cases of this issue, then IMHO the best option is to suggest it here on meta and let 5 other 2.5k+ users do it. No need for another layer of complexity in the system if the gain is not worth it.