# Link failed tag synonym attempts to how to flag for moderater attention

Tags: feature-request

When suggesting version-specific synonyms, even users with high scores in a tag cannot propose a synonym.  However, the error message simply says, "Version-specific synonyms can only be created by moderators."  I propose that the error message include a link to the meta discussion of how to suggest such a tag creation by moderators ([Flag synonym suggestion for moderator](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/89576/flag-synonym-suggestion-for-moderator)).

[image: failed synonym]

Comment: I think the restriction is there because there were attempts in the past to create a tag for every version of a library/OS/etc.. Just my guess, though.

Comment: @nhahtdh That sounds plausible.  I'm not really concerned with questioning the logic behind it; just want to make it easier to suggest such a synonym (particularly in the situation above, where both tags had substantial numbers of questions already...).