# Tag synonyms on main StackOverflow site

Tags: discussion, tag-synonyms, retag-request, privileges

It seems like not very many people care about tag synonyms on Stack Overflow — I often notice tags with obvious duplicates that have never been made into synonyms. To be able to propose new synonyms, however, you need a lot of reputation (2500, whereas I currently have 624).

If there are few questions in a tag, I can retag the questions (having recently earned that privilege), but that's not often going to be a viable solution. Earning more reputation is the "obvious" answer, but it's taken me quite a while to get the meagre amount I already have and I simply don't have the time to spend all day looking for questions I can usefully answer; I have a day job to do  ;o)

So is the only way I can get obvious synonyms fixed — like [open-graph-protocol](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/open-graph-protocol), [facebook-opengraph](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/facebook-opengraph) and [opengraph](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/opengraph) — to post a new "question" here and hope someone does it for me?

Comment: I believe that's the only way to do so, yes. We do it all the time on SU, since nobody really has enough reputation in all tags to do this.

Comment: Related questions: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/88333/why-we-dont-make-the-tag-synonyms-suggestion-work-as-for-the-suggested-edits (on which I have commented on the top-voted answer) and http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/89576/flag-synonym-suggestion-for-moderator

Comment: Also, sometimes synonyms that are obvious to you might not be obvious to everybody. In the above case, yeah, that's *quite* obvious, but maybe you overlooked something :)

Comment: That's a fair point — and I'm sure there are plenty that are obvious to other people but not to me. My main point, though, is the duplicate of http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/88333/why-we-dont-make-the-tag-synonyms-suggestion-work-as-for-the-suggested-edits : the synonym threshold is unrealistically high and there is no means of _suggesting_ synonym that a moderator could approve, in the way that edits to questions (and their tags) can be suggested for moderator approval. Very frustrating.

Comment: Any documentation on how tag synonyms work?