# How do I flag tags as duplicates?

Tags: support, tags, flags, tag-synonyms

I saw 3 tags for the exact same thing (as far as can be figured from their names): `thread-local`, `threadlocal` and `threadlocals`

All of which don't have a Wiki edit either - how do I mark them as duplicates for the moderator to merge them?

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/70710/what-are-tag-synonyms-how-do-they-work

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This Meta post is probably sufficient.  A moderator would be able to create those tag synonyms, and do the batch retagging needed.