# I can vote for tag synonyms, but I don't have a single post in that tag

Tags: bug, status-completed, tag-synonyms, privileges

The [tag synonym list](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/synonyms?filter=suggested) on Stack Overflow offers [udf](/questions/tagged/udf) as one of the tags I can vote synonyms to.

Well, I did have [one post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3426197/continuously-execute-an-emacs-lisp-function/3427517#3427517) in that tag, but since 20 days ago I have [none](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A387076+%5Budf%5D) (the tag had been misapplied to that [one question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3426197/continuously-execute-an-emacs-lisp-function); note that it hadn't been present in the [original revision](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/3426197/1) either).

It looks like the tag creation privilege verification is either using long-obsolete information or not tidying up properly.

The [tag synonym FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/70710/what-are-tag-synonyms-how-do-they-work) isn't clear on what the rules are, but I'm pretty sure “users who have had enough upvotes in that tag at some point” isn't desirable. I'd expect “users who currently have enough upvotes in that tag” (with perhaps some caching, but not that long).

Comment: some of those udf synonyms don't seem right, but some are obvious

Comment: It seems I can vote for synonym tags I have not suggested, when they are listed under the "suggested" tab, even if I don't have up-votes for the master tag. It doesn't happen for synonyms shown under the "all" tag, for which I get the message, "You do not have the required score on this tag to vote for this tag synonym." I don't know if this is by-design, or not; if it is by-design, then the explanation reported in the synonym page needs to be changed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That would be cause I had a rather silly bug.

```
-- remove additional
delete ut 
from UserTagTotals ut 
left join #temp t on t.TagId = ut.TagId and t.UserId = ut.UserId 
where ut.Id is null
```

Should have been...

```
-- remove additional
delete ut 
from UserTagTotals ut 
left join #temp t on t.TagId = ut.TagId and t.UserId = ut.UserId 
where t.TagId is null
```

300,000 rows were just successfully deleted.

This was a **caching only issue**. We build a cache daily for the various [top user](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/bug/topusers) pages, and also happen to use it for the vote check.

Comment: Wow.. that looks like a headache! +1