# How do you create tag synonyms?

Tags: feature-request, tags, tag-synonyms

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What are tag synonyms? How do they work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/70710/what-are-tag-synonyms-how-do-they-work)

Is the tag synonym creation only possible by moderators?  If not how do you create them? There are list of synonyms in the tag synonyms list, but there is no provision to create or add new entity to the list.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

**To create a tag synonym:**

1. Click on a tag, any tag, anywhere you see it displayed on the site.
2. Click on the "synonyms" link.

   [image]
3. Enter the name of the tag you want to propose as a synonym in the text box, and click "Suggest".

   [image]

---

Note that there are certain requirements for proposing a tag synonym, documented in the tag synonyms page. Specifically, to suggest tag synonyms, you must:

- Have more than 2500 total reputation.
- Have a total answer score of 5 or more on the *master* tag for which you are proposing the synonym.

If you *don't* meet the reputation requirements to propose a tag synonym but feel *very strongly* about the merit of your suggestion, then please post a new question here on Meta, and tag it with the [discussion](/questions/tagged/discussion) and [tag-synonyms](/questions/tagged/tag-synonyms) tags. This allows the community to discuss your proposal, and if agreed upon, it can be implemented by several users with sufficient reputation or a moderator.

Comment: It would be nice if they put this in the wiki