# Should a synonym be created for cf9 and coldfusion-9 as they are the same?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tag-synonyms

According to [How do you create tag synonyms?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/99990/how-do-you-create-tag-synonyms) I don't yet have enough reputation for creating a synonym. So I'd like to submit a proposal for someone a with a sufficient reputation or a moderator to consider.