# A tag synonyms proposal: pkg-config

Tags: discussion, status-completed, stack-overflow, tag-synonyms

Following the [How do you create tag synonyms?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/99992/193306), I'm creating a tag synonym proposal for [pkg-config](/questions/tagged/pkg-config): [pkgconfig](/questions/tagged/pkgconfig).

There is 10 questions tagged with [pkgconfig](/questions/tagged/pkgconfig).  All of them are talking about [pkg-config](/questions/tagged/pkg-config), and many questions are tagged with both [pkg-config](/questions/tagged/pkg-config) and [pkgconfig](/questions/tagged/pkgconfig).

[The project page](http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/pkg-config) is titled "Software/pkg-config", so it is a natural choice to keep [pkg-config](/questions/tagged/pkg-config) as a tag and have [pkgconfig](/questions/tagged/pkgconfig) as a synonym.

Answer (score 1):

I generally don't like to create synonyms for tags that are so low in number.  Instead, I've manually retagged the 10 that were previously [pkgconfig](/questions/tagged/pkgconfig) to [pkg-config](/questions/tagged/pkg-config).

Now, the auto-complete should lead people to the new, hyphenated tag.  If we find that people are consistently putting in [pkgconfig](/questions/tagged/pkgconfig), then we'll create the synonym.

Comment: Given that people won't *be able* to pick `pkgconfig` once the hyphenated one is the only one that exists, I don't think that a synonym will ever really be needed here.