# Which required tag should be used with [tag:synonym-request]?

Tags: discussion, synonym-request, required-tags

There are 436 questions on Meta SE tagged under [synonym-request](/questions/tagged/synonym-request). Of these, 211 are tagged with [support](/questions/tagged/support), 197 are tagged with [discussion](/questions/tagged/discussion), and 35 are tagged with [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request).

Since every meta question must include [at least 1 required tag](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16681/show-required-tags-when-asking-a-question-on-meta), which tag should be used for synonym requests?

Comment: Are you requesting also some synonyms to this tag?

Comment: @peterh I am not requesting synonyms. I'm asking, out of the 5 choices for required tags, which tag should be used for questions about retag request

Answer (score 2):

Throwing my own hat into the ring, I suggest using the [discussion](/questions/tagged/discussion) tag. [This answer by Cody Grey](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/99992/351462) sums up my reasoning fairly well.

> If you don't meet the reputation requirements to propose a tag synonym
>   but feel very strongly about the merit of your suggestion, then please
>   post a new question here on Meta, and **tag it with the [discussion](/questions/tagged/discussion) and
>   [tag-synonyms](/questions/tagged/tag-synonyms) tags. This allows the community to discuss your proposal,
>   and if agreed upon, it can be implemented by several users with
>   sufficient reputation or a moderator.**