# Should I accept my own answer on a discussion if no other answers were posted?

Tags: discussion, accepted-answer, self-answer, behavior

Around three months ago I posted the question *[Which required tag should be used with [tag:synonym-request]?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/294834/351462)*, looking for feedback on what tags should be used in a [synonym-request](/questions/tagged/synonym-request).

I included [my own self-answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/294835/351462) suggesting that the [discussion](/questions/tagged/discussion) tag be used, hoping that my initial answer would help spark more discussion. Unfortunately, after 80 days and 30 views, it seems that there wasn't much interest in the question.

In the absence of other posts, I'm considering setting my suggestion as the accepted answer. However, I'm not sure how I feel about self-accepting my own answer on an open-ended question designed to start a discussion.

**Should I self-accept my own answer on a discussion if there aren't any other answers?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I doesn't sound like you particularly *want* to accept your answer. If you're still interested in any future discussion that may come along, **you certainly don't need to.** Accepting an answer is a completely voluntary activity, but doing so doesn't sound like it serves any particular purpose here.

Frankly, I always felt like accepting an answer makes the problems statement look essentially *resolved* (as in "no more help needed here"). So if would still be interested in any future potential discussion on this topic, I feel that accepting your own answer *will* make any [discussion] all the less likely, in my opinion.

It is entirely up to you.

Comment: I'm pretty sure there are a lot of people who think that the "accept" feature should be disabled on Metas.

Comment: @Catija Perhaps with the exception of "support" questions, being the only meta "questions" that actually ask a question that can be given an objectively verifiable answer.

Comment: @Servy sure. There are certainly exceptions but I think we've all seen disgruntled users who write Meta posts and someone else writes an answer that agrees with them but isn't actually the "correct" answer but they accept it because it is the answer they want, not the network-accepted policy.