# Tags with identical meanings: canvas vs. html5-canvas

Tags: discussion, support, synonym-request

As per John's suggestion, edited to a request for a tag synonym:

I would like to propose that [canvas](/questions/tagged/canvas) be a synonym for [html5-canvas](/questions/tagged/html5-canvas).  Although [canvas](/questions/tagged/canvas) is clearly the more popular of the two, the idea of using such a generic word to tag something far more specific doesn't sound quite right.

Comment: It sounds to me like you want a [tag synonym](http://stackoverflow.com/privileges/suggest-tag-synonyms).  If I were you, I would [read up on those](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/70710/what-are-tag-synonyms-how-do-they-work) and edit this question (shouldn't take much) to be more of a "Can we put a synonym here?" than a "What should we do here?"

Comment: I personally don’t like tags that have a generic meaning in programming to be tied to a particular technology. When I think of canvas, I don’t think of HTML.

Comment: @John I hadn't heard of tag synonyms.  That's exactly what I was looking for - thanks.

Comment: @Bavarious I agree - the canvas tag seems to be misused fairly often, probably for this reason.  I think inappropriately-tagged questions would be more likely to be retagged appropriately if `canvas` synonymed to `html5-canvas`.

Comment: I see that the [tag:canvas] wiki explicitly states that it's for the HTML5 version. I think this is wrong.

Comment: I've updated the tag wiki to make it more generic for now.

Comment: @ChrisF - I still can see no difference between [canvas] and  [html5-canvas] description on stackoverflow.com

Comment: @shabunc - it was changed back - http://stackoverflow.com/posts/3625324/revisions - not long after I changed it. It's still wrong and needs updating again. I don't have the time right now to do it.

Comment: @ChrisF, the thing is that de-facto [canvas] and [html5-canvas] questions are exactly identical, so even if tag will be edited again, it won't change anything. Moreover, people will keep tagging questions about canvas without distinction between 'canvas in wide sense' and 'canvas in html5'. So, really, I think it's better to merge this tags.

Comment: @shabunc - I agree. However, I'm not active enough in these tags to propose the synonym.