# How to remove duplicate tags?

Tags: discussion, support, tag-watching

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What are tag synonyms? How do they work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/70710/what-are-tag-synonyms-how-do-they-work)

When I was searching for my favorite tags, I found three tags which are almost identical:

[java-ee-5](/questions/tagged/java-ee-5), [javaee-5](/questions/tagged/javaee-5) and [javaee5](/questions/tagged/javaee5).

The second one and third one do not have any number associated with them. Instead they have **s** in the bracket.

`javaee-5(s)`

`javaee5(s)`

What does it mean?

If they are redundant, how can one delete them?

Comment: It means that they are synonyms - see http://stackoverflow.com/tags/java-ee-5/synonyms

Comment: what do u mean by synonym?elobarate

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/70710/what-are-tag-synonyms-how-do-they-work

Comment: these are not removed but declared synonyms which mean nothing to worry about for you for java-ee-5, javaee5, javaee-5, java-ee5, jee5, and jee-5: http://stackoverflow.com/tags/java-ee-5/synonyms

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(s) means that it's synonym. It means that when you search for javaee-5, you'll get results for master tag [java-ee-5](/questions/tagged/java-ee-5). If you delete master one from your favourites, others should diappear