# Is it right that [pythonic] is synonymized to [python]?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, tags, tag-synonyms

I just tried to search for questions tagged [pythonic](/questions/tagged/pythonic) and, to my surprise, got all [python](/questions/tagged/python) questions as a result. That's not what one would expect, is it?

I haven't really looked into these problems before, but the [FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/70718/181223) says:

> A tag synonym is usually a tag that has exactly the same meaning as some other tag

I see a clear difference between **pythonic** (complying to good Python practices and style, "idiomatic") and just being related to Python.

Here's a link to the [SO Python tag synonyms](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/python/synonyms). The synonym was created on Jul 5 at 12:41, as the [tag synonym list](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/synonyms) says.

The same [faq](/questions/tagged/faq) answer I linked to also states:

> There is no tool for correcting a bad synonym. The only recourse is to
>   post a question to Meta Stack Overflow explaining the problem with the
>   synonym relationship. If enough people/the correct people agree, the
>   site admins can make the change manually.

That's why I'm posting this.

P.S. If I'm wrong and the synonym is correct, I'd still like to know a way to search for [pythonic](/questions/tagged/pythonic) questions (although I guess I can't search for a tag synonym and not the master tag).

Comment: Sounds like a bad tag to me, much like `best-practices` was.

Comment: @Matthew That's a valid point. Actually, the reason I was searching for those question is that I wanted to post a Meta question about the tag being appropriate and the corresponding questions being on-topic.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think the original idea was to merge discussions about what is [pythonic](/questions/tagged/pythonic) with discussions about [python](/questions/tagged/python) in general to be more consistent with other language tags. When I ask if something is [pythonic](/questions/tagged/pythonic), I am asking if my code exhibits good practice and good use of the language python, while if I was asking a similar question in [c](/questions/tagged/c), I don't use [c-onic](/questions/tagged/c-onic), I just use the [c](/questions/tagged/c) and ask my question within the scope of that tag. The distinction becomes both less meaningful and more confusing.

Comment: c-onics, now that belongs on [Math.SE](http://math.stackexchange.com)

Comment: c-onic is pronounced "psionic" maybe? Synonym with [tag:philip-k-dick]

Comment: Just the fact that there's a term "pythonic" should tell you something.