# Redundant tag names: Make one tag redirect to another tag

Tags: discussion, support, tags

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What are tag synonyms? How do they work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/70710/what-are-tag-synonyms-how-do-they-work)

On StackExchange sites, is it possible to make one tag be automatically replaced with another tag? I've noticed that "quotations" is a valid tag on the English StackExchange, but "quotation" is not. I want "quotation" to be an alias, or alternate name, of the "quotations" tag.

Comment: It's called a [tag synonym](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/70710/172958), and you should post a request on the English.SE meta site.

Comment: Should the request be posted as a question on the site, or in some other way?

Comment: Yes, those requests get posted as questions on Meta English.SE, and they wear the `[tag-synonyms]` tag. Examples: [Newest 'tag-synonyms' Questions - English Language and Usage Meta - Stack Exchange](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tag-synonyms)

Comment: Post it as a question on the [English meta site](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/), see [these](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/search?q=synonym) for a few examples.