# What happened to XSD?

Tags: support, stack-overflow, tags, tag-synonyms

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What are tag synonyms? How do they work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/70710/what-are-tag-synonyms-how-do-they-work)

I am trying to get things tagged [xsd](/questions/tagged/xsd) I get [xml-schema](/questions/tagged/xml-schema) instead. Why?

I'm sure  people familiar with the subject understand the difference between these two; even the info on the `xml-schema` tag says "Not to be confused with the more specific "XML Schema" or XSD[...]".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a tag synonym of xml-schema: https://stackoverflow.com/tags/xml-schema/synonyms
So whenever you use [xsd](/questions/tagged/xsd) it will be changed into [xml-schema](/questions/tagged/xml-schema) instead.

Comment: They're not. One is a generalization of the other. Who determines this and can it be undone?

Comment: They are. :) Perhaps they should  not be. If you think so you can always open a discussion here clearly stating why they should not be tag synonyms and that you like to see this synonymization reversed.