# Reverse synonymization of xsd and xml-schema tags

Tags: support, status-completed, tag-synonyms

I am trying to get the "synonymization" between [xsd](/questions/tagged/xsd) and [xml-schema](/questions/tagged/xml-schema) reversed. It was suggested to me [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/144209/what-happened-to-xsd) to open a "discussion" about it, to explain why I believe this should be undone.

My argument is that the [xml-schema](/questions/tagged/xml-schema) is a generalization of the [xsd](/questions/tagged/xsd); having them as synonyms is the same thing as saying, for databases as an example, that there should be no tags for Oracle, DB2 or MSSQL because there's one for databases. Or there shouldn't be one for C# or Java, etc. because we have one for a programming-language. Or even better, let's all drop Apache and IIS tags, and stick to one: http-servers...

The tag info on [xml-schema](/questions/tagged/xml-schema) clearly indicates:

> Not to be confused with the more specific "XML Schema" or XSD, the
>   general term "XML schema" may refer to, among others:

By the same token that made [xsd](/questions/tagged/xsd) an [xml-schema](/questions/tagged/xml-schema), it should happen the same then for [schematron](/questions/tagged/schematron) or [relaxng](/questions/tagged/relaxng)... Why would these be given any different treatment?

If I want to ask a specific question on how to achieve referential integrity of a model described using the W3C XML Schema language definition (XSD), why would I tag that xml-schema? What would a Relax-Ng guy care about my post?

These different XML schema languages have their own implementations, and support communities. Why bundle these into one?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I've gone and removed the synonym.  The tag wiki for [xml-schema](/questions/tagged/xml-schema) is also very clear that it's a general blanket term and the tag for [xsd](/questions/tagged/xsd) is more specific, so I would say that the tags are set up correctly.

I'd recommend keeping an eye out for retagging things to be more specific when they're dealing with XSD.

Comment: It seems to have crept again, i.e. xml-schema is now a synonym for xsd (as opposed to xsd being a synonym for xml-schema). Is there a way to make it go away?