# Deter “synonymization” between certain tags

Tags: feature-request, tag-synonyms

It seems that things that happen for a "good" reason, may repeat; here "good" means "understandable confusion".

It happened with the [xsd] tag marked as a synonym of [xml-schema] on SO. It got cleaned (see [Reverse synonymization of xsd and xml-schema tags](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/144213/reverse-synonymization-of-xsd-and-xml-schema-tags)).

It happened again, in reverse this time: [xml-schema] as an [xsd] synonym.

I would take the provided recommendation "to keep an eye on it" (see above response) and bring it as a feature for moderators, to have the ability of placing a "not-synonyms" mark between the two. If someone tries it again, at least they get a note (otherwise lost in the noise) why they shouldn't do it; and if they insist, they could take it up with the moderators, the same way one had to justify the removal of the synonymization to begin with.

Comment: That second synonym was created clear back in December of 2012 (the same year of that other question you linked) and has existed for over two years since then, and has even been merged now (as in, there's no going back anymore).

Comment: @animuson, I think your comment makes my point even stronger. I am also surprised to hear that "there is no going back anymore"... it makes me laugh actually. As an involved user for a while, I think that the result of "created clear back" might not have been that visible after all... It reminds me of a Vogon demolition order... Thank you.

Comment: I'm not really sure it makes your point any stronger. This is a pretty rare situation already, and the fact that it went over two years without getting noticed again suggests that it's *not* all that bad of a synonym. And by "no going back" I mean that, since the tags have been merged, all the old tags have been completely remapped to the master tag now. Removing the synonym would just result in one tag with all 8,000 questions and a non-existent tag (since it would have 0 questions, the synonymized tag would just cease to exist).

Comment: Even though I am a pretty frequent user of the xsd tag (I didn't care a bit about the xml-schema one), there was nothing prominent to indicate an "imminent" and "irreversible" merge of tags. Suggestion to improve this, maybe send notification to top users that something for which there is no going back is about to happen. And it is a bad synonym, considering it clearly stated "not to be confused with XSD"; and in my books, bad is bad no matter how rare it is.

Comment: There are lots of things that could be vastly improved about the synonym system as it exists. But if you want to discuss the viability of this particular synonym, feel free to head over to [Meta Stack Overflow](http://meta.stackoverflow.com) and start a discussion about it. FWIW merges are not automatic. They require a moderator to conduct them. I'm probably the one that merged the tags too, because it was an incredibly old synonym and there was nothing to suggest that they were different when I was going through the list of questions.

Comment: Thank you for reaching out; you said "there was nothing to suggest ..."; a deterrent such as the one I suggested here, should've provided you or whoever did it (on top of the clear tag info - unless it was changed in between, I have no way to see it in its pre-merge state), with the information needed to resist an impulse to clean something in the system that should not have been there to begin with. And maybe the action would've been to remove the "old synonym" instead of merging it. I'm all good, thank you again.

Comment: No one would ever have seen the other tag wiki because they were synonymized, so only the tag wiki for the master tag is displayed. I tried finding it in the orphaned tag wikis tool we have just now (out of curiosity), but nothing relevant came up.