# Tag synonym showing up with uses in tag suggestions list

Tags: bug, tag-synonyms, tag-autocomplete

On Ask Ubuntu, in the retag dialog, I noticed:

[image: bug]

Notice that [fontconfig] shows up as both a synonym and a regular tag (which somehow has 4 usages). Clicking through "fontconfig" shows it does seem to be an ordinary synonym.

As I recall, normally if you start typing the name of a synonym, only the synonym target is shown up (with the name of the synonym bolded/highlighted); the synonym shouldn't be displayed as a separate tag.

I presume the bug comes from "fontconfig" still having usages, even though according to [What are tag synonyms and merged tags? How do they work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/70710/what-are-tag-synonyms-how-do-they-work), synonymized tags are supposed to always have 0 uses.

Answer (score 2):

This is due to the fact that when a synonym gets approved, it doesn't automatically merge all the existing questions into the new tag; only moderators can do that. So that tag **still exists** somewhere out there with 4 questions tagged under it, [in an unsearchable state](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/115670). Until those questions get retagged to the master tag, the tag will continue to appear in the list (because it *does* have question under it), but will get remapped to the master tag if someone attempts to use it.