# Proposing a tag synonym

Tags: support, tag-synonyms, synonym-request

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What are tag synonyms? How do they work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/70710/what-are-tag-synonyms-how-do-they-work)

How can I propose a tag synonym? Sorry if this is already answered somewhere, but I was unable to find it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you simply post it as question on meta, specifying the tags you want updated. Use [synonym-request](/questions/tagged/synonym-request) and it should be handled by the moderators.

The FAQ post [What are tag synonyms and merged tags? How do they work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/70710/what-are-tag-synonyms-how-do-they-work) clearly states how it works.