# Unable to change [stl] tag to [stdlib] -- comes out as [std] tag

Tags: bug, tags

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What are tag synonyms? How do they work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/70710/what-are-tag-synonyms-how-do-they-work)

A moment ago I was trying to edit the tags in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13821048/printing-byte-representation-of-stdstring).

I edited out the [stl](/questions/tagged/stl) tag, and tried to replace it with the [stdlib](/questions/tagged/stdlib) tag.  However when I saved my edits and viewed the question anew, the [stl](/questions/tagged/stl) tag was actually replaced by the [std](/questions/tagged/std) tag.

I'm not sure what's happening here.  Is it a bug in the system, or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 7):

[stdlib](/questions/tagged/stdlib) is [a synonym](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/std/synonyms) of [std](/questions/tagged/std), so it's automatically remapped when you save the edit.

Comment: Makes sense, but this raises a whole batch of new questions.

Comment: @JohnDibling You could ask them separately, or if they're closely related, edit them into your question

Comment: @Asad:  I'm going to ask them seperately, but I need to gather my thoughts on it first.

Comment: @JohnDibling Yeah, I have no comment on the validity of the synonym or anything like that. It was apparently suggested on June 9th of this year.