# Create tag synonyms on Stack Overflow for the notification-area tag

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, tags, tag-synonyms

I have just edited the tag wikis on Stack Overflow for the tags [notification-area](/questions/tagged/notification-area) and [system-tray](/questions/tagged/system-tray), and one reviewer rightly rejected the edit for [system-tray](/questions/tagged/system-tray) to say that it should instead be a synonym for [notification-area](/questions/tagged/notification-area).

I don't yet have enough reputation to suggest tag synonyms, so I'm hoping a moderator might make the change if I ask here.

The correct tag is [notification-area](/questions/tagged/notification-area) because "system tray" is a misnomer according to [this article on the MSDN blog](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20030910-00/?p=42583).

There are also tags [systray](/questions/tagged/systray) and [tray](/questions/tagged/tray) which have no wiki entry but are also being used for questions about the system notification area.

In summary, I'm hoping a moderator can make [notification-area](/questions/tagged/notification-area) the definitive tag, and make [system-tray](/questions/tagged/system-tray), [systray](/questions/tagged/systray) and [tray](/questions/tagged/tray) synonyms of [notification-area](/questions/tagged/notification-area).

Comment: Notification-area seems like its far too vague to mean anything, it could probably also refer to the notification bar on iOS or android. I don't think this tag should stay, personally.

Comment: Notification area refers to the part of the desktop environment which anchors the tray icons and system notification messages. It is the correct name for that part of the environment, whereas system tray is an incorrect name for it. (I know that system tray is in common use, but common use does not make something correct.)

Comment: What I'm saying is that this tag doesn't mean anything useful, and it shouldn't exist in the first place.

Comment: Would you also get rid of system-tray, systray and tray on that basis? There are many questions on SO using these four tags in a way which makes sense, so it sounds unhelpful to get rid of them.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What are tag synonyms and merged tags? How do they work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/70710/what-are-tag-synonyms-and-merged-tags-how-do-they-work)

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps [windows-notification-area](/questions/tagged/windows-notification-area) would be better. That is the official name on Windows, but as Richard points out, not all desktops are Windows. Then [system-tray](/questions/tagged/system-tray) and the others can be made synonyms of [windows-notification-area](/questions/tagged/windows-notification-area). Because of the way tag-typing works, if someone starts to type `notif` they will be prompted with this tag to use.

Comment: But the tag is not only being used for Microsoft Windows. It applies equally to use in Linux or Mac OS X, and even on other platforms. Java allows tray icons to be added to the notification area of any of these platforms, so the tag windows-notification-area would seem wrong to a Java developer.

Comment: Are there any questions that would actually apply to the notification area of several different operating systems at once?

Comment: @Kate: Qt has a `QSystemTrayIcon` cross-platform wrapper for the thing. GTK has a similar thing. Having all the "system tray" tags point to a windows-only thing isn't desirable IMO.

Comment: I agree with Mat. The language Java also offers ways to query the notification area as a whole, regardless of platform. (The Java API does wrongly name the class "SystemTray" but it relates to the system notification area.)