# "batch" tag turns into "batch-file"

Tags: support, stack-overflow, tags

I posted a question on SO, intending to use the tag "batch".  After completing the post, the tag mysteriously changed to "batch-file".  I tried editing it several times to switch it to "batch" but each time it reverted to "batch-file" after saving.

This is the post:
[In second batch, exclude workers from first batch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17077455/in-second-batch-exclude-workers-from-first-batch)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That happens because [batch](/questions/tagged/batch) is a synonym of [batch-file](/questions/tagged/batch-file) (and so are [7 other tags](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/batch-file/synonyms)). Synonyms get automatically remapped to the master tag.

See also: [What are tag synonyms? How do they work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/70710/what-are-tag-synonyms-how-do-they-work)

Comment: Thanks.  I was unaware of synonyms.  In this case, too bad, since "batch" was the correct keyword for the context.  Oh, well.

Comment: Would anyone consider undoing "batch" as a synonym of "batch-file"?  It's needed for MechanicalTurk (and probably other contexts, too).

Comment: @PeriHartman I don't know (it would probably take a new meta question to find out). Perhaps a new tag for mTurk batches would make more sense?

Comment: Yeah, the latter is the path of least resistance.  I don't have enough points to do that.  Anyone care to?  I'll suggest "batch-hit" or "batch-assignment".