# Did something just change to cause issues with [css-selectors] tag?

Tags: support, stack-overflow, tags

On two different computers, whether I put in the url string `/css-selectors`, or put `[css-selectors]` in the search or click on the [css-selectors](/questions/tagged/css-selectors) tag, they all rewrite as merely [css](/questions/tagged/css), with the url string being `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/css` instead of `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/css-selectors`.

FYI--At least some other hyphenated tags appear to still be functioning correctly, so it is not simply because of the hyphenated name.

Comment: That no longer occurs: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/css-selectors is not synonymized to CSS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking at a synonym; [css-selectors](/questions/tagged/css-selectors) is now a synonym for the [css](/questions/tagged/css) tag.

See the [css](/questions/tagged/css) [synonyms page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/css/synonyms) for the full list of synonyms.

According to the [tags synonyms overview page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/synonyms) the synonym was created on May 13th. That is the date at which the synonym *proposal* was created and voting starts, I don't think we can see the date when the synonym proposal was accepted.

The proposer of the synonym *did* receive a [Synonymizer badge](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1234256/mooseman?tab=activity&sort=badges) only two hours ago; it is quite likely that that badge was earned for the css-selectors synonym proposal being accepted.

Comment: It wasn't just an hour or so ago. Someone must have just changed that (and if so, I'm not sure I agree with the change).

Comment: @ScottS: I think then that the voting must have completed recently.

Comment: Where does voting for such replacements take place? That seems to be elusive to my locating.

Comment: On the tag's synonyms page. See the [regex synonyms page](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/regex/synonyms) for a currently active proposed synonym. You can also see all currently active proposals on the [synonym overview](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/synonyms?filter=suggested&tab=newest).

Comment: Okay, that explains why I could not find any vote info for [tag:css-selectors]. So the related question would be, how does one get a synonym reversed (or can it be done)?

Comment: You'd have to request that the synonym be removed here on Meta (see the [tag synonym faq](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/70710/what-are-tag-synonyms-how-do-they-work)).

Comment: Thanks for the info, [I did just such a request](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/185358/reverse-the-css-selectors-tag-being-made-a-synonym-for-the-css-tag).