# Synonymize / merge meta-tags: [original-author] & [original-poster]

Tags: feature-request, retag-request, synonym-request, original-poster

**Synonym / retag suggestion:** [original-author](/questions/tagged/original-author)← [original-poster](/questions/tagged/original-poster)
**Question count:** [original-author](/questions/tagged/original-author)= 12, [original-poster](/questions/tagged/original-poster) = 6 <sup>(Not including this feature request.)</sup>
At present, **no tag wikis / excerpts for either** <sup>(*hint hint*)</sup>, and this is the only question that uses both.

I'm open to discussion regarding the choice of master tag. I haven't [suggested](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/synonyms) it formally <sup>(I [can't](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/70718/246931))</sup> yet.

- Personally, I prefer [original-author](/questions/tagged/original-author) a little.
  FWIW, a [chi square test](http://graphpad.com/quickcalcs/chisquared2/) suggests a decent chance that others' preferences are systematic too: 
  *χ*²<sub>(2)</sub> = 2, *p* = .16.  (84% probability of less imbalance if 18 questions' tags were chosen randomly.)
- However, in defense of [original-poster](/questions/tagged/original-poster), we do say "OP" a lot around here...

Comment: they could be the same person, but the usage I have seen (and use myself) is "original-poster" tends to refer to the poster of the question whereas author could be either the author of the question or an answer.  But is that enough of a difference?

Comment: Good point, but I would argue it is not enough, and that the distinction supports original author as the master.  If that can mean both questions *and* answers, why would we need a second tag that is specific to the question author? It's not like either is seeing heavy usage and we need to disambiguate them for the sake of anyone (no one) following these tags.

Comment: Gotta say, I'm kind of amazed this doesn't strike anyone else as "common sense"...