# Merge the “Merge Tags” tool with the synonymous “Create Tag Synonym” tool

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, user-interface, moderator-tools, tag-synonyms

There are two moderator tools to create tag synonyms in one go.

There's a “Merge Tags” tool (`/admin/merge-tags`) which is linked from the list of moderator tools (`/admin/links`). I can also click the “merge” button on a tag page, which leads me to a dialog with the tag's name pre-filled in the “Old Tag Name” box.

[image: /admin/merge-tags]

From the synonyms dashboard (`/tags/synonyms`), I can use the “Create a Tag Synonym” link to bring up a similar interface (`/admin/create-tag-synonym`).

[image: /admin/create-tag-synonym]

One has the “Old Tag Name” above the “New Tag Name”. The other has the “Target Tag” above the “Source Tag”. Talk about confusing!

Please make the interfaces consistent. I have no strong opinion as to whether the source or the target should be above, but the same side should be above on the two dialogs. Or the two dialogs could just be unified — the “Create Tag Synonym” dialog subsumes the functionality of the “Merge Tag” dialog.

Comment: Just to clarify - Doesn't "merge tag" burn the old tag and replace it with the new tag? And "Create Tag Synonym" basically shows them in the general site as well as in the UI (but appears in the question as the synonym-ed tag)?

Comment: @VScode_fanboy: See this FAQ: [What are tag synonyms and merged tags? How do they work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/70710/335251)

Comment: @V2Blast OK, I was right.

Answer (score 7):

These two tools serve *sliiiiiiiightly* different purposes, so merging them would not be appropriate. However, the UI is now consistent across both tools, so I'm marking this [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed).