Should the long existing tag synonyms be merged at some point?
According to the FAQ post on synonyms and merging (current revision): "All good tag synonyms should eventually be merged (source)."
Having a tag synonym which is not merged causes various problems - the most important is probably the fact that the questions which have only the synonymized tag are missing in some searches.1
According to this SEDE query, there are 19 tag synonyms on this site where both the synonymized tag and the master tag contains some questions. (Below I have included the list of the tag synonyms returned by the query.)
Are among them some that are problematic and need some clean-up before merging? Or perhaps are there some synonyms which should be canceled?
For the tag synonyms that are safe, I would suggest that merging them might be a reasonable action. (I am fully aware of the fact that merging is not reversible - so it should be used only in  cases where it is sure that the synonym is going to stay.)
Here is a link to the merging tool - mentioned by a per-site moderator in another discussion.

Here is the list of the tag synonyms returned by the linked SEDE query:

newsletter → community-digests
markdown-rendering → markdown
code → code-formatting
share-this → sharing
latex → mathjax
election-page → election
downtime → maintenance
date-format → dates
lost-reputation → reputation
reputation-page → reputation-history
favorites-tab → bookmarks
custom-question-lists → custom-filters
exploit → security
canonical-questions → canonical
total-reputation → reputation
careers-germany → legacy-stack-overflow-jobs
site-specific-formatting → site-settings
hot-tab → hot-questions
careers-city-pages → legacy-stack-overflow-jobs


1The problems with searching are described, for example, here: Tag synonyms and searching. This post on Meta Stack Overflow is a result of the same issue: Converted tag synonym don't allow to filtering on converted tagged threads.
Recently I made a related post on Mathematics Meta - the post contains an example of this, too. This post mentions also how this influence badges and dupehammer - but that is definitely less important than searching: What are differences between synonyms with and without merging from the practical point of view?

Of course, the situation here is not really that bad - for comparison, SO has almost 1000 tag synonyms with this problem.

Are you counting deleted questions? Given that merging does not change the tag on deleted questions, the vast majority of merges will have left at least some, if not hundreds, of questions with the old tag.

@Makyen The linked query uses the column Count from the table Tags - AFAIK this does not include the deleted questions. Moreover, one can check for the individual tags from the above list that there are indeed questions with that tag - here is the SEDE query from the tag (newsletter). The query is taken from an answer here: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/384858

@Makyen If you're asking in connection with SO - since you're a mod on that site - I have posted an example illustrating this in chat.
