# Make tag synonym process bi-directional

Tags: feature-request, tags, tag-synonyms

For a long time, it seemed that I couldn't suggest tag synonyms. Today, I think I discovered why. I found that if I had no score on a tag (usually because it's a new tag that's almost the same as a standing, major tag) and tried to suggest a synonym, i'd get that rude flag saying I didn't have enough score to suggest it.

Today, I went to the common tag, where I had a high score, and suggested the new tag as a synonym. It worked fine!

Can the code be changed so that if the user has sufficient score on EITHER side of the suggestion, that they can be allowed to execute the suggestion?

ALSO,  I would suggest that the synonym process show the difference so that it is clear which is which. Maybe two entry boxes, marking the master tag and the synonym tag?

It would also be really nice to see my score for each of the two tags in the synonym process.

[EDIT - I split off discussion of top users having synonym privilege into another question at the request of another. It seemed reasonable. ;-) ]

So, what is the consensus?

Comment: I agree with about half of your suggestions. So that I can upvote the bits I like can you make your question into a description of the issue and use answers to provide your solutions?

Comment: I see these as very tightly related.  What do you see as separate issues?

Comment: I think the issue is that synonyms are hard to suggest and implement except for moderators, and is exacerbated when sites are small. You have suggested several things on your question that might make it easier. It is these which I think would be better as answers rather than "answers in question".

Comment: My comments here were not suggesting that you created more questions from it. They were to disentangle answers within your question.

Comment: This is a useful FAQ on who can create tag synonyms and how they are created: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/70710/what-are-tag-synonyms-and-merged-tags-how-do-they-work