# Are [stackexchange-team] and [employees] the same?

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms

[stackexchange-team](/questions/tagged/stackexchange-team) and [employees](/questions/tagged/employees) have similar tag excerpts. None of them have a tag wiki

stackchange-team (23 questions)

> For questions about the team of people behind the Stack Exchange network (developers, community managers, etc.), also known as employees of Stack Overflow (the company).

employees (15 questions)

> For questions about Stack Exchange employees and how they interact with the community

Should they be synonymized or merged?

Reference

- [What are tag synonyms and merged tags? How do they work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/70710/289691)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yep, looks like it.

I picked [stackexchange-team](/questions/tagged/stackexchange-team), both because it's more descriptive and because it's older. And, because [I'm a valued associate, not an employee, dammit!](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/03/25/welcome-valued-associate-josh-heyer/)

I kept [employees](/questions/tagged/employees) as a synonym.