# Synonymize [the-overflow] into [blog]

Tags: discussion, tags, meta, synonym-request

There are two tags for the company blog:

[blog](/questions/tagged/blog) (381 questions)

> This tag is for questions about the Stack Overflow blog, the place for official company communications as well as essays, opinions, and advice on the act of computer programming.

[the-overflow](/questions/tagged/the-overflow) (6 questions)

> For questions about the Stack Overflow blog, home to the newsletter, podcast and company content

The former is more widely used, however the latter is a reasonable name for someone to guess (it *is* the official name of the blog), thus I think it makes sense to synonymize [the-overflow](/questions/tagged/the-overflow) -> [blog](/questions/tagged/blog).

Comment: At the time the latter tag was created, its name only referred to a newsletter, not to the blog.

Answer (score 1):

This post leaves me unsure about almost everything.

1. I'm not sure how synonymizing works but I would prefer the final tag name be [the-overflow](/questions/tagged/the-overflow).
2. I'm not sure if that's the direction of synonymizing that's being proposed.
3. I'm also not entirely sure if *The Overflow* qualifies as *"a blog"*.

   [image]
4. At launch of the newsletter it was said it's called the *"The Overflow"* but perhaps that's short for *"The Overflow newsletter"*.

> [Today we’re launching The Overflow, a newsletter](https://stackoverflow.blog/2019/10/01/introducing-overflow-newsletter-cassidy-williams/)

5. Maybe the tag-wikis need some clarification?!

I don't know  ¯_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: As for #2: I'm proposing [blog] as the final tag names, since I'm pretty sure people would call the blog "blog" over its full name (which I only recently read myself)

Comment: @bobble `the-overflow-blog` would make it easier to discover, I wasn't aware there was *"a blog"* and after referring to it as such I've been told it's *"The Overflow"* . Anyway, renaming the tag is likely a branding choice from the company so I'm curious to see what they think about it.

Comment: Re: #1: [This Q&A explains how suggesting synonyms works](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/70710/335251). Neither tag is currently a synonym of the other, so anyone with at least 2,500 reputation and a total answer score of 5 or more on a given tag (or a moderator of the site) may suggest synonyms for that tag - so they'd go to the Synonyms page from the tag that's intended to be the one that stays the primary name of the tag, and suggest the other tag as a synonym of it. (Also, mods can easily reverse the direction of an existing synonym relationship between 2 tags.)

Comment: So nothing prevents either [blog] or [the-overflow] from being the main tag, with the other one being a synonym pointing to the main tag. (Or the main tag could have some other name like [the-overflow-blog], possibly with those two tags as synonyms of it.) That's up to the community/mods.

Comment: @V2Blast admittedly I haven't been involved in synonymizing other than voting, and usually those discussions are led by more experienced users. But it's a good reminder that ultimately the community gets to decide via vote, although *"the overflow"* refers to a product so I'd expect some authoritative guidance/participation of mods/cms. I suppose this discussion would have been more effective with the MSO audience where a lot more burnination/synonymizing happens. (I'm out of my depth here, so I look forward to more folks chipping into the discussion. Good suggestions btw!)