# How does SO maintains tagging table

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, tags, data-dump, database

While checking SO data dump I have noticed that SO stores tags as an array inside Post table. And at the same time there is a mapping table with `TagId` and `PostId`. I assume this is used for tag counting and search by tag functionality. What I want to know is how does SO inserts data into mapping table. 
Here is the scenario : let us assume that I have created a post/question with 5 tags. Obviously a record will be added into Posts table. What I want to know how records will be added to mapping table. Is there a trigger which will run 5 inserts into mapping table ?
Is there a background process which will take care of this ?

**UPDATE**: This is not a duplicate of [How is the tagging system implemented here at S[O|F|U]?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/25710/how-is-the-tagging-system-implemented-here-at-sofu), if you will check the question and the answer to it will become obvious. There is nowhere decried how SO stores the post and tags into tables.

Comment: Why would it need to be a trigger or background process?  The same *foreground* process that creates the "posts" entry would create the entries in the mappings table, all at the same time.

Comment: @Servy I was thinking about it too, but I though may be it can be slow.  May be there is a special trick that SO developers are using.